# Rename CSV file with value from 1st column with batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I would like to rename my CSV file with the value from the 1st column. How can I do that?

Example CSV:

```
123ABCQ;TEST1;TEST2;.....;;;;;
```

previous file name:

```
output.csv
```

new file name:

```
123ABCQ.csv
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: I have Testes this, but  it is not working: set oldcsv=Output.csv
set newcav=filename.csv
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%oldcsv%) do copy %newcsv% %%i.csv

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask], and [edit] your post to include an [mcve].  It seems you need to investigate `help for` and `help set`.  Your question has almost certainly been asked in the past. Did you even try to do any research on this problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no evidence that you've done the required research (see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5DParse+csv%3F  and  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5Drename+file%3F).

Comment: by copying your comment into the question (and format it for readability) you would make the question on-topic and avoid downvotes and closure.

Comment: There are no columns, or rows in a CSV file, only fields, and records. So I think we've determined that you're looking for the string in the first field of your semicolon separated text file. The next question is how many records are there? and from which record are you trying to capture the first field? Most CSV files have one or more header records; are there any in this one? and is that where you're trying to capture the string from? The only answer supplied currently has guessed that you want the string from the first field of the first record, and that the first field cannot be empty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `tokens=*` you tell `for` to take the whole line (in short terms), but you want the first element only. So instead of `tokens=*`, use `"tokens=1 delims=;"`. You can omit `tokens=1`, as it's the default anyway. You then have to prevent it to (try to) rename the file again with the first token of each other line. `& goto :cont` breaks the loop, so it runs just for the first line.

```
for /f "delims=;" %%a in (output.csv) do ren "output.csv" "%%~a.csv" & goto :cont
:cont
```